# How to run zookeeper & kafka-server on docker avoiding `Connection refused` exception?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run a kafka-spark streaming application on Docker. Below is my project structure.

[image]

Dockerfile contents:

```
from gcr.io/datamechanics/spark:platform-3.1-dm14

ENV PYSPARK_MAJOR_PYTHON_VERSION=3
WORKDIR /opt/application/

RUN wget https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.2.5.jar
RUN mv postgresql-42.2.5.jar /opt/spark/jars

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY main.py .
```

Docker-compose.yml contents:

```
version: "2"

services:
  spark:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
  spark-worker:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "22181:22181"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
      - ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME=2000

  kafka-server1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper-server:2181
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-server
```

I was able to pull the images and create containers successfully.

```
(venv) (base)  johnny@Johnnys-MBP~/PyCharmProjects/dockerpractice/Johnny> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                                                    NAMES
d47d4b091b2c   confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   16 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes      2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:22181->22181/tcp   zookeeper
59c06d3cf754   confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest       "/etc/confluent/dock…"   48 minutes ago      Up 48 minutes      9092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:29092->29092/tcp                       kafka
26794da88c7d   bitnami/spark:3                    "/opt/bitnami/script…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                                                            dockerpractice-spark-worker-1
5a308035bd18   bitnami/spark:3                    "/opt/bitnami/script…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                                   dockerpractice-spark-1
```

I connected to the kafka zookeeper image and started it like below:

```
docker run -i -t confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest /bin/bash
zookeeper-server-start /etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties
```

The above command starts zookeeper with no exceptions and I tried to start my kafka-server in the same way:

```
docker run -i -t confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest /bin/bash
kafka-server-start /etc/kafka/server.properties
```

But when I submit the command for kafka-server, I see the below exception:

```
[2022-04-04 18:13:11,276] WARN Session 0x0 for sever localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, Closing socket connection. Attempting reconnect except it is a SessionExpiredException. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:344)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1290)
```

I tried various combinations like changing the ip address & ports of kafka server to new ones and by creating multiple kafka servers but all of them are resulting in same exception.
Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here and how can I correct it?

Comment: Running Kafka on Docker is not easy. I advise you to read https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/ and https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/